# Datos en tiempo real de consola C# en Laravel

Tags: php, c#, laravel

Buen dia.  la verdad acabo de entrar en un terreno en el que ni idea.
necesito conectar una balanza (puerto rs232) para ver el peso en mi aplicativo laravel.

la forma que lo hice   fue atreves de un aplicativo de consola C#  el cual llamo desde php.

lo que necesito es ver en tiempo real los cambios que tiene el peso de la balanza, pero no se como ejecutar de forma continua  la consola de c# dentro de PHP

**este es le codigo php**

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
// ultima linea de la salida en $ultima_linea. Almacena el valor de
// retorno del comando en $retval.
$ultima_linea = system('C:\Users\richa\source\repos\ports\ports\bin\Debug\ports.exe' ,$retval);
// Imprimir informacion adicional
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Ultima linea de la salida: ' . $ultima_linea . '
<hr />Valor de retorno: ' . $retval;
?>

    <input type="" name="" value="{{$ultima_linea}}">
```

**y este es el código de consola C#**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            // Cree un nuevo objeto SerialPort con la configuración predeterminada.
            SerialPort Puerto_serie = new SerialPort("COM7");

            Puerto_serie.BaudRate = 9600;
            Puerto_serie.Parity = Parity.None;
            Puerto_serie.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            Puerto_serie.DataBits = 8;
            Puerto_serie.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            Puerto_serie.RtsEnable = true;

            // Establecer los tiempos de espera de lectura / escritura.
            Puerto_serie.ReadTimeout = 2; // Milisegundos.
            Puerto_serie.WriteTimeout = 2;

            // Detecta cualquier dato recibido.
            Puerto_serie.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            Puerto_serie.Open(); // Abrir puerto.

              byte[] miBuffer1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$"); // Codificación ASCII y guarda en la variable array tipo byte.
              Puerto_serie.Write(miBuffer1, 0, miBuffer1.Length); // Envía los datos del buffer todo su contenido.

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey(); // Espera pulsar una tecla cualquiera.
            Puerto_serie.Close(); // Cierra el puerto serie.
        }

        // Detecta cualquier dato entrante.
       public static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string entradaDatos = sp.ReadExisting(); // Almacena los datos recibidos en la variable tipo string.
            Console.WriteLine(entradaDatos); // Muestra en pantalla los datos recibidos.
            
        }
            
    }
```

me da los datos que necesito dentro de laravel, pero debo recargar el navegador cada vez que hay un cambio en el peso.

**tengo la siguiente llamada ajax,** esta cerca a lo que quiero pero se que se puede mejorar

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                lista();
            $(peso1).change(function(){
                lista();
            });$(peso2).change(function(){
                lista();
            });

            function lista(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'{{route('pesaje._puerto')}}',
                        method:'POST',
                        data:{
                                _token:$('input[name="_token"]').val(),
                            }
                    }).done(function(res){
                        $('#peso1').html(res);
                    })
            }
        })
```

**me retorna lo siguiente cada vez que cambio el valor de los input** [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**por otro lado la consola C# me retorna lo siguiente**
(los pesos no coinciden por que utilizaron la balanza al momento de la captura ) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La pregunta aunque interesante puede terminar cerrada pues luce como basada en opiniones, si agregas lo que hayas intentado para obtener los datos de forma continua ayudaría mucho

Comment: Gracias @BetaM sinceramente desde PHP no he intentado nada,  desde la consola C#  esta leyendo continuamente los cambios  de la balanza, con un intervalo de 2 ms

Comment: Trata por ejemplo con una llamada ajax o algo que a la comunidad le de un punto de partida claro para ayudarte